# Android AsynTask Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, room

Поддерживаю Legacy - проект, и как минимум у одного из пользователей приложение падает.

В MainActivity имеется settings, на который ссылаются из всех фрагментов.

Падение связано, как вы понимаете с lateinit, на момент вызова, она не проинициализировано.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IOnBackPressedFilter, OnBackPressListener {
   lateinit var settings: Settings

   onCreate(bundle: Bundle?){
        val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        val settingsDao = db.settingsDao()
        AsyncTask.execute {

            settings = settingsDao.get
            try {
                if (settings.id != "") Crashlytics.setUserId(settings.id)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Предполагаю, что ошибка возникает, из-за не срабатывания данного кода в Application (Settings в Database пуст)

В Application на этот случай есть запрос.

```
try {
            val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
            val settingsDao = db.settingsDao()
            AsyncTask.execute {
                try {
                    val settings = settingsDao.get
                    if (settings.token == "") {
                        val temp = Settings()
                        temp.apiUrl = settings.apiUrl
                        settingsDao.insert(temp)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    settingsDao.insert(Settings(apiUrl = ConstantsApiUrl.BaseURL))
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Crashlytics.log(e)
        }
```

И я не понимаю, почему это происходит. Такое ощущение, что Insert не срабатывает, но он вроде должен сработать

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface SettingsDao {

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM settings")
//    fun get(): Single<Settings>

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM settings")
    val get: Settings

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM settings")
//    suspend fun getSus(): Settings

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(settings: Settings)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun update(settings: Settings)

//    @Delete
//    fun delete(settings: Settings)

}
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Keep
data class Settings(
    @PrimaryKey var sid: Int = 1,
    var token: String = "",
    var id: String = "",
    var type: String = "1",
    var avatar: String = "",
    var email: String = "",
    var legalEntityType: Int = 0,
    var fio: String = "",
    var rating: String = "0",
    var phone: String = "",
    var city_string: String = "",
    var balance: String = "",
    var balance_freezed: String = "",
    var bonus_acc: String = "0",

    var infoTime: String = "",

    var verified: Int = 0,
    var hasTesting: Int = 0,

    var latitude: String = "",
    var longitude: String = "",

    var approval: Int = 0, // 0 -> standart, 1 -> big //Не нужно
    var push: Boolean = true, //Возможно надо избавиться и убрать на сервер
    var premium: Int = 0,
    var autoRecPay: Int = 0,
    var orderHideComission: Boolean = true,

//     dev режим
    var apiUrl: String = "",
    var apiChanged: Long = 0L, //Таймер по отправке версии приложения пользователя

    var login: Boolean = false,

    var versionFAQ: String = "",

    var rated: Boolean = true,
    var versionApp: Int = 0,
    var lastAppOpened: Long = 0L, //время последнего показа инфо об обновлении

    var lastOpenMyOrder: Long = 0L,
    var lastOpenBalance: Long = 0L,
    var lastOpenProfile: Long = 0L,


    var minPrice: Int = 0,
    var timeLocal: Int = 0, //0 - time, 1 - local, но не точно

    var foot: Int = 1,
    var car: Int = 0,
    var middleCar: Int = 0,
    var bigCar: Int = 0,

    var orderDayVisible: Int = 1

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю ответ здесь предельно прост. Ваш AsyncTask (тот который в Application) не успевает выполнить операцию до загрузки вашей Activity.

Решение:

- Вынести этот код в активити и запускать второй AsyncTask по окончанию первого.
- Вынести код из Application вообще в отдельную сущность, которая будет запускаться в стартовой Activity и получать из этой сущности колбек об успехе/ошибке операции и только тогда запускать второй AsyncTask.

Первый вариант быстрее, но второй более правильный.